# How to configure Ubuntu Server to point to my registered website's domain?

Tags: dns, domain-server

First off, I'm aware that it's a possibly a duplicate, but what happens is that no matter what I try to google, read, and setup, I'm just unable to fully understand how to do it. Why? Let's take "example.asd" as example. Something about it is the "domain name", something about it is the "nameserver", something about it is the "DNS" even though some registered domains can directly point to IP address, my router is already setup to a "DNS" so it can solve URLs, and so on. I'm very confused about it, and whathever I find simply confuses me even more.

I bought and registered my webpage's name at http://www.nic.cl. As it seems, domain's control panel doesn't accept an "A record" to be setup. It only accepts "Nameservers" (DNS?), these urls that, in case of services such as 000webhost, are like the following:

ns01.000webhost.com
ns02.000webhost.com

Using 000webhost as example, everything I know I have to do, is setup an account pointing to my registered/bought webpage's domain, and finally setup the domain to point back to these "nameservers".

From a local host, how to configure either Apache or Nginx to point to my domain, and how to host a "nameserver"?
Do I REALLY need to buy a "DNS" or something like that (if I understood correctly)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Does anything [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/point-domain-name-website.shtml) help you understand better?

Comment: Yes. Now my question is: How may I setup my own DNS here? I think that's only left to connect my domain with my local host; but, do I really need to pay for a DNS setup?